# discrete-time and continuous-time transfer functions with Gekko sysid

Tags: python, gekko

In a project, I have to use python language to tune the PID coefficients of the boiler de-super-heater control loop. So, I use the Gekko package to identify the plant transfer function. After identifying the ARX model, I need to convert it to the discrete and continue time transfer functions to be able to tune this loop with PID tuning methods. According to the results, I do not know whether I use this package correctly or not. Are the following 3 lines of code written correctly?

```py
y, p, k = m.sysid(np.linspace(1, u[0], num = u.shape[0]), u, y, 2, 2, pred='meas')
gp_d = control.tf([p['b'][0][0][0], p['b'][0][1][0]], \
                   [1,-p['a'][0][0],-p['a'][1][0]], dt=1)
gp_c = d2c(gp_d, method='zoh')
```

What role does the coefficient k play?
Is it true to write [1,-p['a'][0][0],-p['a'][1][0]] as the denominator of a discrete-time transfer function?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

K is the gain matrix, and you should use the variables to make the code clear

extracting them like so:

```
linspace = np.linspace(1, u[0], num = u.shape[0])
y, p, k = m.sysid(linspace, u, y, 2, 2, pred='meas')
```

Comment: I knew k is the gain matrix. My question is what role does it play in converting the ARX model to the transfer function model. Generally, what is the benefit of k?

Comment: Each element of `k` is the steady-state gain between each input Manipulated Variable (`u`) and output Controlled Variable (`y`). There is additional description of the ARX model here: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/ARXTimeSeries

Comment: thank you. Are the above 3 lines written correctly? gp_d is the discrete-time transfer function and the parameter k is not used in creating it.

Comment: It looks correct from the documentation.  https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/control.tf.html To verify, you could create a step function result using the `m.arx` gekko function and a step response of the `control.tf()` model. They should give the same result.